# Command Handling = Slash Command Permissions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

You have the command handling, for example:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('avatar')
        .setDescription('Get the avatar URL of the selected user, or your own avatar.')
        .addUserOption(option => option.setName('target').setDescription('The user\'s avatar to show')),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('target');
        if (user) return interaction.reply(`${user.username}'s avatar: ${user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })}`);
        return interaction.reply(`Your avatar: ${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })}`);
    },
};
```

Now the question, how can I integrate the slash command permissions?

Comment: Do you mean a)`scope for slash commands` or b)`you want to run slash commands only for a particular user`, or am i getting it wrong? What I mean is, what exactly do permissions mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the **[`GuildMember#Permission#has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=has)** method while getting the `GuildMember` object from **[`Interaction#member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=member)** like so:

```js
let flag = `ADMINISTRATOR`; // permission flag needed 
if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(flag)) {
    return await interaction.reply({
        content: `You Don't Have The Permisssion To Execute this command, must have the following permission: **${flag}**`,
        ephemeral: true
    });
}
```

Comment: I know, however, it should be the case that the command is grayed out for unauthorized people, so it cannot be selected!

Comment: You're looking for [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ApplicationCommandPermissions)